# When I upgrade to Windows XP SP3 does it automatically upgrade Internet Explorer 6 to the latest version?

Tags: windows-xp, upgrade, internet-explorer, sp3

Is this a pre-packaged process or does SP3 only modify core Windows files?

Comment: Oh wow. For a minute I thought you were seriously asking if it would upgrade to the latest version of IE6. Phew.

Comment: I notice, IE 8 is now a "critical" update to windows instead of optional now.

Answer (score 11):

> When I upgrade to Windows XP SP3 does it automatically upgrade Internet Explorer 6 to the latest version?

In a word: no

You'll have to [download the installer for Internet Explorer 8](http://www.microsoft.com/windows/internet-explorer/default.aspx) separately.

However, it is possible to slipstream (integrate) Internet Explorer 8 into a Windows XP installation CD, as well as Service Pack 3, drivers and the latest bugfixes (i.e. with [nLite](http://www.nliteos.com/))

> Windows XP SP3 does include updates to
>   both Internet Explorer 6 and Internet
>   Explorer 7, and it will update
>   whichever version is installed on the
>   computer.

[Source (PDF)](http://download.microsoft.com/download/6/8/7/687484ed-8174-496d-8db9-f02b40c12982/Overview%20of%20Windows%20XP%20Service%20Pack%203.pdf)

Comment: Well I know you need to install IE8 manually, but what about IE6. Will it automatially upgrade my IE6 to the latest version, or will it just leave it to what it was prior to the SP3 upgrade? Thanks

Comment: updated the answer, sorry for the misunderstanding.

Comment: SP3 does not change any major software. So whatever you have will remain unchanged.

Comment: Ah, I was reading it the same way too.